# How to make wrapper class forward its constructor arguments to std::vector's constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, variadic-templates, forwarding, function-templates

I have a `wrapper` class to wrap an `std::vector<int>` data member. I want the `wrapper`'s constructor to forward its arguments to the `vector<int>`'s ctor. I tried to use a variadic template constructor to implement this. Since `std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3}` is constructed by its `std::initializer_list` ctor, I want the `wrapper` to activate `vector`’s `initializer_list` ctor when I do

`wrapper mywrap{1, 2, 3}`.

But I didn't get the desired result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct wrapper {
    std::vector<int> v;
    template <typename ...Tn> wrapper(Tn ...args) : v(args...) {}
};

int main() {
                                                            //----Output----
    wrapper wrap1{ 1 };
    std::cout << wrap1.v.size() << std::endl;               // 1
    std::cout << wrap1.v.at(0) << std::endl;                // 0
    wrapper wrap2{ 1, 2 };
    std::cout << wrap2.v.size() << std::endl;               // 1
    std::cout << wrap2.v.at(0) << std::endl;                // 2
    wrapper wrap3{ 1, 2, 3 };                               // error
    wrapper wrap4{ std::initializer_list<int>{ 1, 2, 3 } }; // OK
}
```

The output shows:

`wrapper wrap1{ 1 };` calls `explicit vector (size_type n);`.

`wrapper wrap2{ 1, 2 };` calls

`vector (size_type n, const value_type& val, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`.

`wrapper wrap3` fails when `initializer_list<int>` is not specified.

In all cases, I wanted the `vector`’s `initializer_list<int>` ctor to be activated. How can this be fixed?

Comment: All problems and questions are since v(args...) should be v{args...}.

Comment: @ForEveR make it the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's difference between initialization by `()` and initialization by `{}`, in your constructor you should also use `{}` initialization.

```
template <typename ...Tn> wrapper(Tn ...args) : v{args...} {}
```

By the way, if you want only `initializer_list` c-tor, why not simply write this c-tor?

```
wrapper(std::initializer_list<int> args) : v(args) {}
```

Comment: Although now `wrapper(1,2)` won't behave like `vector(1,2)`.

Comment: @ForEveR Thanks, that fixes most of the code. But would you please explain #1a and #3? Without the fix, shouldn't `wrapper wrap1{ 1 };` fail to compile because of `vector`'s `explicit` ctor? Without the fix, isn't #3 unambiguous?

Comment: @ForEveR: As @Mike Seymour said, "now `wrapper(1,2)` won't behave like `vector(1,2)`". With your fix, the prior yields a container of elements with values `1` and `2`, and the latter yields a container of an element with value `2` only. Is there a way to make the interface look & behave exactly the same for all cases? By the way, I understand using the `initializer_list` ctor, but I want to learn about argument forwarding to accommodate all ctors, including ones I might not know about in advance (i.e. proxy template implementation that can take all ctors but limits other methods' interfaces).

Comment: @CodeBricks it's real. You should write ALL constructors for this case. I think it will be perfectly to do one with initializer_list and one template without it, that will forward args by `()` to vector.